# How to customize the header in my report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Q :

I want to make the header in my report like this but I don't know how to do this in right way.

[image]

They are three columns with a general header (GPA) and special header for each one which its value comes from a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Report Designer:

- You will need two heading rows, so (if you don't already have them) right-click on the existing heading row and select Insert Row.
- Enter 'GPA' into the top heading row cell above the first of your three parameter-based columns, and your three parameter-based headings into the appropriate cells on the second header row.
- Click on the GPA cell, then hold down Shift and click on the next two cells so that the three top row heading cells above the parameter-based columns are all selected. Right-click on the selected cells and select Merge Cells.
- With the merged cells still selected, set alignment, bolding and background colour as required.